# possible Intercept MDX Query

Tags: c#, ssas, mdx

Say I wanted access the following OLAP cube but I wanted to limit my users to only see specific product category of "bikes" and not "clothing" because of security. Is there a way to modify the MDX query going to the cube or make a C# dll that would recieve all the data then modify all of the MDX query ?

http://sampledata.infragistics.com/olap/msmdpump.dll

if you want to see the actual data

https://www.igniteui.com/pivot-grid/remote-adomd-provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSAS has roles. You add user and restrict "bikes" member within a cube for the role.

See [this](http://easyroles.com/2014/01/conventional-method-to-add-a-new-role-in-ssas/) article, for example.